# What does the http-protocol handle?

Tags: http, cookies, network-protocols

I have a specific question about the http-protocol?

I know that the http protocol handles request/response, but does it also handle the cookies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cookies are set using HTTP Response headers and sent using HTTP Request headers.

See also: [the original](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109) and [updated cookie specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)

Comment: are there any more things that the http protocol handle ,except cookies and request/response?

Comment: Correct, but cookies are defined in http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6265.html

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are transported in HTTP requests and responses, but are not part of HTTP.

See [RFC 6265](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6265.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It handles cookies. All cookies are sent over HTTP requests of the same cookie domain parameter (including wildcard domain).

Answer (score 0):

YES this same protocol is responsible for handling the cookies.. i mean the browser that says that it can handle HTTP protocol shud also handle cookies.
see the link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Implementation 
and there are a lot more things in HTTP other than Req/Res and cookies.. in fact the cookie thing is a part of the req/res.
visit this link 
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html